# How to check if meta box value is false for all posts then do something based on that

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, metabox

I have the following code in template-home page which queries for a custom post type, called reviews. I have a Meta Box for the Custom Post Type where I can write the Author, Article Link, an excerpt to be displayed on the Home Page and a checkbox. If the checkbox is checked that post gets pulled on the Home Page.

```
 <?php 
        if(have_posts()) {
            while(have_posts()) {
                the_post();

                // store the page content for future use
                $home_content = get_the_content();

                if(has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
                    <div class="rounded-image">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    </div>  
                <?php }
            }
        } 
        // RESET ORIGINAL QUERY POST DATA
        wp_reset_postdata(); 
    ?>
<?php
// START THE SECOND QUERY TO RETRIEVE THE REVIEWS

    $args = array('post_type' => 'reviews');
    $home_reviews_query = new WP_Query($args);

    if($home_reviews_query->have_posts()) {
        while($home_reviews_query->have_posts()) {
            $home_reviews_query->the_post();

            // Retrieve Meta Box Options
            $checked_review = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'review_check', true);
            $review_author = esc_html(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'review_author', true));
            $review_excerpt = esc_html(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'review_excerpt', true));
            $review_content = get_the_content();

            if($checked_review && $review_content != '') { ?>
                <blockquote>
                    <?php if($review_excerpt != '') : ?>
                        <p>
                            <?php
                                echo $review_excerpt;
                            ?>  
                        </p>
                    <?php elseif($review_excerpt == '') : ?>
                        <p>
                            <?php 
                                the_excerpt();
                            ?>
                        </p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <cite>- <?php echo $review_author; ?> -</cite>
                </blockquote>
            <?php }                     
        }// end while           
    } // end if

    // RESET SECOND QUERY POSTDATA
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>
```

I would like that if there aren't any posts checked, I could display something else instead of the reviews, like the_content() for the Home Page, as backup in case someone forgets to check any reviews. 
I was thinking I could check if $checked_review is false for all posts and if that returned true it would then display some other bit of content. However I have no idea to properly do that.

I tried the following piece of code in the loop and after the loop but with no result.

```
if($checked_review == false) {
   echo $home_content;
}
```

I previously stored the Home Page the_content() in the $home_content variable. before I started the query for the Reviews Post Type.

Had a go with get_posts() as well but to no solution. Hopefully my post is not too confusing.

I'm not that good with PHP so any suggestions/push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't clear how you are getting $home_content but you will need two loops: one to get the home page content, however you are retrieving that, and one for your reviews content above. You will need to use wp_reset_postdata() after both loops.

Comment: after the get_header() I'm just doing a normal loop where I also make use of the post_thumbnail() and i'm also storing the page content into that variable. I'm using reset_post_data() before the second query.

Comment: Updated the first post to make it more clear. Apologize I didn't make it clear the first time.

Comment: Is $home_content empty? If not, can you just do:

`if($checked_review && $review_content != '') {
// Output reviews
} else {
echo $home_content;
}
`

Comment: The $home_content has some lorem ipsum. I had already tried what you suggested above but that outputs the $home_content for every other review that isn't checked. Also tried 'if($checked_review)' outside the loop and if there's even one review that isn't checked it outputs the $home_content regardless if there are any checked. I need a way to check all the reviews for that meta box value and if all of them are unchecked then display the $home_content just once. I feel like there's probably an easy way to do this and I'm just missing it.

Comment: What I'm not clear about is your set-up. You say you are using a custom template for this but what posts is the first loop pulling in? I'd suggest creating a home.php template and adjusting your first loop to pull in a post from a category called 'Home page'. Here is an example of something similar I use: http://pastebin.com/1HzbN0SB

You probably need $checked_review to be an array $checked_review[] = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'review_check', true); so that it isn't replaced each time in the loop. Then out of the loop check if (sizeof($checked_review) > 0) { ...

Comment: I am using a template-home and the first loop just pulls the default data from the template. I didn't open a new WP_Query cause the $post global is set automatically to pull from there, right ? Unless I somehow misunderstood that. Anyway, the great news is that your suggestion to store the $checked_review in an array worked wonderfully. I am then using, outside the loop, !in_array() to check if the 'yes' value is not present and if it's not it displays the $home_content. Such a relief. I can not begin to thank you enough. Thank you so, so much for sticking with me here. Thank you!